# Why AbortError: The operation was aborted. when updated time in html5 video?

Tags: javascript

How to make fast time rewind?

AbortError: The operation was aborted. Drops 100 times and slows down the progress bar.

How to fix it or to stick a pause between time change?

```
function eventStartMove(event) {
    document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', eventDragMove);
}


function eventDragMove(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    let percentLen = 100 / this.offsetWidth;
    percentLen = percentLen * event.pageX;
    let percentDuration = videoEl.duration / 100;
    percentDuration = percentLen * percentDuration;

    setTimeout(function () {
        videoEl.currentTime = percentDuration;
    },100);

}

function eventStopMove(event) {
    document.body.removeEventListener('mousemove', eventDragMove);
}

document.querySelector('.wrapper-bar').addEventListener('mousedown', eventStartMove);

document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', eventStopMove);
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle seeking position when user is clicking on `progress bar` element:

```
<div class="progress-bar">
</div>


function handleSeek(event) {
    const rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const positionPercent = (event.x - rect.left) / rect.width;
    const seekToTimePosition = videoEl.duration * positionPercent;
    videoEl.currentTime = seekToTimePosition
}

document.querySelector('.progress-bar').addEventListener('click', handleSeek);
```